# Any efficient RTOS with display support present for Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: hdmi, display, freertos

I would like to know if any RTOS with display support (preferably HDMI) is present for Raspberry Pi 2?

I'm not looking for a simple RTOS port that just does an LED ON/OFF.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between a simple RTOS and the one you are looking for?  Which RTOS have you already considered and discarded?

Comment: @joan I have considered  [FreeRTOS](http://www.osrtos.com/rtos/freertos) and  [ChibiOS RT](http://www.stevebate.net/chibios-rpi/GettingStarted.html) initially. Both are ported into Rpi but not sure how well the existing port can handle something like HDMI display.

Comment: Why do you want an RTOS? The HDMI bit is an odd requirement for one.

Answer (score 1):

Is Xenomai/Linux an option for you ? If yes, look [here](https://github.com/awesomebytes/xenorasp)

Comment: Xenomai/Linux looks very promising but I would like to know whether it is in a stable state or in beta. Also does it supports the display part?